# Android Facebook unity 5.0.3 plugin issues

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am getting two issues with this plugin.

1: When I call this code below I get an API error code of 1 inside the Facebook dialog.

```
FB.Feed (linkName: "Space Bird", linkCaption: "I just made the distance of " +pdist+"km! How far can you go?", link: "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wms.app.spacebird");
```

Is there something wrong with it?

2: On my Facebook account in my app, the sharing button works, but if I use someone else's account, it shows the dialog that this app will like to post on your behalf (or something like that) and if you hit OK, it disappears.

This is what I got for debug for that:

```
02-21 14:40:26.350: V/FBUnitySDK(5497): sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"cancelled":true,"key_hash":"keyhashhere"})
02-21 14:40:26.840: V/FBUnitySDK(5497): sending to Unity OnFeedRequestComplete({"error":"not logged in"})
```

And yes, I do have the correct keyhash on Facebook.

So, what should I try for both of these issues?

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix for the problem ?

Comment: Not sure about the first one.  Does it work inside the Unity Editor.

For the second one have you tried calling FB.Logout() to switch users?  Android has this habit of leaving around old sessions even if the person is logged out of their device.

Alternatively is your app live on facebook?  If the app hasn't gone live and the alternative account isn't allowed by your app, they won't be able to post.

Comment: @BrianJew So, I looked on my facebook developer page and the app is live and available to all users (It is a solid green dot), so why is it not allowing others to post?

Comment: @BrianJew And I have been testing on multiple devices each with its own facebook account. So no, I haven't used FB.Logout() yet.

Comment: @BrianJew and thanks for your suggestions. If you have anything else for me to try, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**#1:**

There is a bug on our side, and we will try to fix it as soon as possible.

If your link contains dots in get parameters, the feed will fail.

One of the temporary workarounds is to use a [URL shortener](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening).

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks. Now I just need a fix for #2.